# graphics problem in xubuntu 14.04: images and text disappear

Tags: nvidia, graphics, nouveau

I recently migrated from Win XP to Ubuntu, and I have been having a very annoying graphics problem ever since. I am currently running Xubuntu 14.04, but I do not have the impression that the exact Linux version matters much, because the problem was not there under XP, but under both Lubuntu and Xubuntu. As the problem is a bit hard to "pigeonhole", a longer description follows here:

Menu entries appear sort of "greyed out" as soon as the mouse hovers over them (i.e. when they are highlighted) (not really greyed out, but shown in a silvery whitish colour) which makes it hard to read them. Against some backgrounds, it is almost impossible to read these highlighted entries.

In some applications, notably synaptic, list entries are not shown (or disappear as soon as they have been displayed for a microsecond). You can sometimes make them temporarily visible by using the scroll wheel, but the visibility is very fleeting, and not predictable. You also see that the entries are definitely "there", because you can move among them using the cursor keys, and in the lower window, which shows the package descriptions, the descriptions change.

In Thunar (but it used to be the same in pcfmman under lubuntu), icons almost only appear over or beside those entries that the mouse is hovering over. Folder icons, when they are there, partly lose their blue color and are shown in white.

In Firefox, most of the tiles in the graphical menu disappear after having been shown for a microsecond or so. They also can be made to appear briefly by moving the mouse over them, or by clicking and dragging, but the effect is not very predictable.

Often a part of the background shines through, notably when you type something on the command line in a terminal window. You then see only a part of the background instead of what you have typed, and you can usually make this disappear if you place the terminal window somewhere else, or when you minimise the window which is shining through.

Notably, the fleetingly-visible list entries were already present in Xubuntu's graphical installer (e.g. when selecting the language), and (as I already said) in Lubuntu.

In evince, pages become suddenly invisible. When you scroll, they reappear. This is quite reliable.

No xorg.conf is being used at all.

The graphics adaptor is an NVidia GeForce4 MX 4000, the kernel driver used is nouveau. The kernel is passed the kernel option:

drm_kms_helper.edid_firmware=VGA-1:edid/1680x1050.bin

via GRUB, to make the the desktop fill my monitor correctly (which works fine).

This is all the technical information I can think of at the moment. Can anybody give me any suggestions on where to look further?

Comment: Try nvidia-current(-updates) instead (install via the Driver Manager)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the NVidia's proprietary driver.

Open the Ubuntu Software Center, and go to Edit->software sources. There, open "Additional drivers" and select the nvidia one. It will take a while to install.